# "aes_crypt_null_safe 2.0.2" Source file does not exist ERROR on Android

Tags: android, flutter, flutter-dependencies, assets

I need to load AES encrypted Image from assets to memory and display it with `Image.memory()`.
when I compile the code for windows it run without errors, but when I compile it for android emulator it give Source file does not exist path error.

```
    String encFilepath = './assets/Question-2.png.aes';

    Uint8List? img;
    var crypt = AesCrypt();

    class MyHomePage extends StatelessWidget {
      const MyHomePage({super.key, required this.title});

      final String title;

      Uint8List decryptFileToMemorySync(String encFilepath) {
        Uint8List bytes = crypt.decryptDataFromFileSync(encFilepath);
        Img.Image image = Img.decodeImage(bytes) as Img.Image;
        Uint8List imagePng = Img.encodePng(image);
        return imagePng;
      }

      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        crypt.setPassword('WX5DgtHQ8OC4l0h9a jtvg5u7 fBSNYrc2gMhuAzOpg xZbrhFBQGYdnSLv4FeQ27myJbSh     NFRhebA3kln2Tv');
        crypt.setOverwriteMode(AesCryptOwMode.rename);

        var x = decryptFileToMemorySync(encFilepath);

        return Scaffold(
          appBar: AppBar(
            backgroundColor: Theme.of(context).colorScheme.inversePrimary,
            title: Text(title),
          ),
          body: Center(
            child: FittedBox(
              child: Column(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                children: <Widget>[
                  const Text(
                    'Decrypted Image:',
                  ),
                  Image.memory(x, color: Colors.black),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ),
        );
      }
    }
```

on windows it run and display the image:

[image: windows]

the same code on android it give error:

[image: android]

how can I get it to work for android?

Comment: Assets in Android are not files, so you have to use different code for loading assets, see here https://docs.flutter.dev/ui/assets/assets-and-images#loading-flutter-assets-in-android